# How does adding members reduce backwards compatibility of classes?

Tags: c#, oop, extension-methods, backwards-compatibility

I'm learning about C# extension methods at the moment.  I have read in a couple of places that adding members to classes reduces backwards compatibility for code that uses those classes.

I've read this here: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2007/03/10/extension-methods-best-practices-extension-methods-part-6/

And page 418 of Troelson's Pro C# book.

I'm afraid this doesn't make sense to me.  Surely any code that uses instances of those classes as they WERE before extra members were added (without using extension methods, just by adding them to the class), will still be able to call all the old methods, properties, fields and constructors just like before, as they haven't changed.  Even if the new members can change the state of the object, they will never be called in the old code, so therefore the code is backwards compatible.

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: You don't see how changing the code that is run when a given method is called on an instance of a type from one implementation to another could possibly affect that code in some way?

Comment: I didn't see it as changing the code, rather adding to the class.  Obviously I can see it is dangerous fiddling with code on which other classes are dependent.  However, adding a method overload that will take priority over the original method for certain parameters (which could be used in the old code method calls) like in the accepted answer below is a clear example of exactly what can go wrong that I hadn't thought of.

Comment: @GeorgeWooding, Added a second example to my answer.

Comment: @GeorgeWooding You don't think having an implementation that you had written for your program replaced with an entirely different implementation written by someone else, potentially for an entirely different purpose, isn't a change to that program?  And the example in that answer has nothing at all to do what's described in the article you linked, which describes its behavior rather specifically.

Comment: @Servy, I believe the second example is more relevant, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The case in discussion is adding members to a class and nothing else.  As mentioned I am learning about extension methods so I can't verify if the second example is correct, however the first example clears this issue up for me perfectly, so I accepted it.  Feel free to edit his/her answer or downvote it.  Devuxer has also at least attempted to show an example of extension methods reducing backwards compatibility, which I believe is perfectly relevant to paragraph 4 of the article.  Have a good weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here's one possible way adding a new method could actually break client code...**

```
void Main()
{
    var oldFoo = new OldFoo();
    var oldResult = oldFoo.Calculate(2, 2); // 4
    var newFoo = new NewFoo();
    var newResult = newFoo.Calculate(2, 2); // 0
}

public class OldFoo
{
    public int Calculate(params int[] values)
    {
        return values.Sum();
    }
}

public class NewFoo
{
    public int Calculate(params int[] values)
    {
        return values.Sum();
    }

    public int Calculate(int value1, int value2)
    {
        return value1 - value2;
    }
}
```

**And here's another way, specifically dealing with an extension method...**

Initially, the client defines an extension method to give `Foo` the ability to `Combine`:

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    var result = foo.Combine(2, 2); // "22"
}

public static class Extensions // added by client
{
    public static string Combine(this Foo foo, params int[] values)
    {
        return string.Join(string.Empty, values.Select(x => x.ToString()));
    }
}

public class Foo { }
```

Later, the developer of `Foo` adds a new `Combine` method to the class:

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    var result = foo.Combine(2, 2); // 4
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Combine(this Foo foo, params int[] values)
    {
        return string.Join(string.Empty, values.Select(x => x.ToString()));
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Combine(params int[] values)
    {
        return values.Sum();
    }
}
```

Note that the extension method gets effectively blocked or *shadowed* by the new `Combine` instance method.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that extension methods may share the same namespace with member methods and if they do, member methods take precedence sheerly by name. The implication of this is that you, as a library developer, may break code of a client who introduced an extension method to your class in his own application. Without you being able to know that you are doing it.

If you update your library class with a new member method and your client installs the update, he may find your new method has the same name as the extension method he added earlier. Or he may not find it if the argument lists are compatible. His extension method will now be hidden by your new member method. His code will now either not compile (incompatible argument list), or, worse, behave differently.

Answer (score -1):

A real world analogy might help.  Think about it like machinery.  Imagine someone designs an engine that people start using as a basis for some equipment, say a harvester.  If the engine designer decides a fuel filter would be helpful and adds that in, it could ruin the harvester design because that design may have put something in the space now occupied by the new fuel filter.

Adding the new member (the fuel pump) decreased the backwards compatibility.  The harvester design was based on a version backward in history.

And a more programming based example: A app designer creates a parser for his application that behaves in a particular way.  After release, it's discovered that the parser does not implement the spec correctly for some uncommon conditions.  A new version is released that correctly implements the spec but adds a flag to provide the previous behavior.